# Dynamically Change a CSS Background Image Based on Data in a Database (WordPress)

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm building a WordPress theme and the site has a background image applied to the body of the document using CSS.

I want to allow the client/admin to be able, through the use of theme options, to upload and change this image. So I was wondering what the best approach would be to dynamically changing the background image either using PHP, JavaScript or jQuery to pull through the image? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dropdown box for select a color and do the ajax call on change event of dropddown box like this using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#colorchange").change(function(){

       $("body").css('background',$(this).val()) ;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Hey Thanks. What I really wanted to do was allow the user to upload an image in the backend that would then change the background image.